# Pytest override fixture scope

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I pytest, we declare the fixture scope (function, module, class, session) at the fixture definition.
Is it possible to override that scope at the usage of it in a test? So that I can have a default function-scope fixture, but some tests which are using it use it as module-scope?

My concrete scenario is that I'm using parametrized tests, but I want my fixture to be used once over all parameters. Otherwise, the fixture is good to have function scope for all other tests.

Comment: You could create a module-scope copy of the fixture by doing something like `mod_fixture = pytest.fixture(func_fixture.__wrapped__, scope="module")`, and then use that instead of the original fixture. But I'm not sure if this would always work.

Comment: There's [dynamic scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#dynamic-scope), but you won't be able to modify it from test. Aside from that, you can override fixtures per module, e.g. you declare a session-scoped fixture `foo()` in `conftest.py` and a function-scoped `foo()` in `test_module.py` which passes the parent `foo` through.

Comment: @hoefling - may be can turn this into an answer - this question pops up every now and then.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53749291/3217306

Comment: @hoefling can you provide an example of overriding fixtures like this because this is not working for me. Do I have to define it in conftest or can I define a fixture in another module, import it, and pass it through to the module's overriding fixture?